# Error D/permissions_handler( 5642): No android specific permissions needed for: 9

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

I'm trying to request Storage Permission on Android Using permission_handler to change the wallpaper on the lockscreen but it's always permission denied even though I've set it to a condition when permisston denied it will request permission, but I always get a `Permission Denied` response for android storage I get a response like this

```
D/permissions_handler( 5642): No android specific permissions needed for: 9
I/flutter ( 5642): Android Storage Permission Status: PermissionStatus.denied
```

#### Steps that I do

1. I tried to set android storage permissions like this

```dart
 // asking permission
  _askPermission() async {
    if (io.Platform.isIOS) {
      var photosStatus = await Permission.photos.status;
      if (photosStatus.isDenied) {
        await Permission.photos.request();
        print("Photos Permission Status" + photosStatus.toString());
      }
    } else {
      var photoStatus = await Permission.photos.status;
      var storageStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (storageStatus.isDenied) {
        await Permission.storage.request();
        print("Android Storage Permission Status: " + storageStatus.toString());

      } else if (photoStatus.isDenied) {
        await Permission.photos.request();
        print("Android Photos Permission Status: " + photoStatus.toString());
      }
      // Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [Permission.storage].request();
      // print(statuses[Permission.storage]);

    }
  }
```

well I always get a denied response for android storage like this

```
D/permissions_handler( 5677): No android specific permissions needed for: 9
```

and storage permission always denied

```
PermissionStatus.denied
```

here is a my android manifest for permission

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wallpaperapps">
    <!-- Manifest -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:minSdkVersion="30" />

   <application
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you found the solution ?

Comment: Please update the image_picker plugin to 0.8.6+4, and if you use the camera plugin, update to 0.10.3+2 too.

Answer (score 0):

for Android 33, use Permission.mediaLibrary.status instead of Permission.storage.status. You can check it by device_info_plus plugin. Like this;

```
late PermissionStatus status;

if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt <= 32) {
    status = await Permission.storage.status;
}  else {
    status = await Permission.mediaLibrary.status;
}
```